# Replace size parameter in css

Tags: c#, css, regex, replace

I want to replace all font-size-parameters in a html document (css attributes).
I'm using .net with c#.
I guess it could be done with some regular expression.

Am I forgetting some other ways to set the font size?

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
             .t {
                 font-size: large;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="font-size: medium" />
    </body>
</html>
```

into:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
             .t {
                 font-size: large_replaced;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="font-size: medium_replaced" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use relative unit like em, ex etc for all font dimensions in your page. By adjusting 
only html elements' size you manage all fonts

big fonts

```
html{
 font-size:18px;
}
```

smaller fonts

```
html{
 font-size:18px;
}
```

you can manage that form javascript, better (also using cookies).

Comment: But I want to replace them :)

Comment: I'm setting this to the correct answer, because in the end this was the solution I went for. I was able to solve my above question, but the result wasn't good. So anyone that tries this, don't! :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following regex to find where to replace:

```
/style=\"[.]*font-size:(?<size>[^;]*);[^\"]*[\"]/
/<style[^<]*font-size:(?<size>[^;]*);[^<]*[<]/
```